# Source code definition of `==` for lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Does anyone know how **exactly** `==` is defined for lists in Haskell? I've tried Hoogling it but can't seem to find where the instance `Eq [a]` is defined.

Comment: Oh wait, [Hoogle isn't a typo!?](https://hoogle.haskell.org/)

Comment: @richardec xD Nope, Hoogle is a very useful resource for Haskell programmers.

Comment: @richardec hahaha nope. It's like my lifeline when coding in Haskell :)

Comment: @Silvio @ hegash Hah, for the first 10 minutes I though it was a typo for "googling", until I searched on SO for the same "typo"...and found that it's more than common :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GHC implementation of `Eq` and other built-in instances is written in [`GHC.Classes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.8.0/docs/src/GHC.Classes.html). Specifically, you're looking for [`Eq [a]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.8.0/docs/src/GHC.Classes.html#local-6989586621679084910)

> ```hs
> instance (Eq a) => Eq [a] where
>     {-# SPECIALISE instance Eq [[Char]] #-}
>     {-# SPECIALISE instance Eq [Char] #-}
>     {-# SPECIALISE instance Eq [Int] #-}
>     []     == []     = True
>     (x:xs) == (y:ys) = x == y && xs == ys
>     _xs    == _ys    = False
> ```

Nothing super exciting. Two empty lists are equal, and two nonempty lists are equal if the heads and tails are equal. Finally, two arbitrary lists are non-equal. The only interesting part is the specialization directives, which should monomorphize equality checks on integer lists, strings, and lists of strings.